# why it doesn't continuously write in textfield?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, material-ui

i want to make page to get user information.

this is codesandbox.io page.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-z1x3q?fontsize=14

when i inputed continuously "d" in 성별* textfield.

but i can input "d" just one time.
if i want to input more i have to click 성별* textfield and then input "d"

could you help me?

there is no error message. just do not write continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the following inside the body of `function Certify()`

```
  const gender = useinput("");
  const birthday = useinput("");
  const phone = useinput("");

  const certifys = [
    { key: "성별", state: gender },
    { key: "생일", state: birthday },
    { key: "번호", state: phone }
  ];
```

[Check the correction](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-njeg3)

Answer (score 0):

you incorrectly implemented form, implemented like this :

```
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    gender: "",
    birthday: "",
    phone: ""
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  function Certify() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {Object.keys(values).map((certify, index) => (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} key={index}>
              <TextField
                required
                label={certify.key}
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={certify.value}
                fullWidth
              />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

[this is new sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ne11y) look at